# After Android Studio 3.2 update all of my FAB icons are tiny and in the top right corner

Tags: java, android, xml, drawable, floating-action-button

UPDATE:
You can override the normal and mini sizes by adding the following to values/dimens.xml:

```
<!-- Overriding sizes of the FAB -->
 <dimen name="design_fab_size_normal">90dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="design_fab_size_mini">30dp</dimen>
```

OR

//set XML attribute

```
app:fabCustomSize"100dp"
```

[image]

So I am developing an application that I am close to publishing to the app store. I updated android Studio to 3.2 and even though the release notes don't specify any changes to the FAB itself, somehow all of my FAB icons are now suddenly tiny and stuck in the top right corner of the FAB!

-This problem persist not just in one activity but in multiple.

-No I did not (at least not Intentionally) alter the parent FAB

-I have no custom FAB Style, nor am I extending the FAB parent class widget

-I tried changing "app:fabSize" to both mini and normal to no avail

-I tried adjusting the fab gravity to no avail

I am stuck here, all suggestions are welcome!

-Again the FAB with these very same attributes worked fine earlier and the only dynamic alterations to the FAB are using a Color.filter to change the color of the icon.
-below is my XML, that was working perfectly a few day ago.

-These XML drawables are all housed in the drawable folder (iIeven tried drawable v-24)

```
//here is the actual icon xml 
<vector android:height="24dp"
android:tint="#000201"
android:viewportHeight="24.0"
android:viewportWidth="24.0"
android:width="24dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<path android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData.../>
</vector>
//HERE IS THE FAB XML ATTRIBUTES
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/submit_fab_roster"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:longClickable="true"
                android:onClick="onClickSubmit"
                android:src="@drawable/submit_fab_2"
                android:tint="@color/black"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/red"/>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but please understand that the version of Android Studio has nothing to do with the behavior of your app.  The problem you're having is not related to this.

Comment: That's what I figured, rarely has a new release broken anything in my app, but I don't now what else it could be. The only thing I have changed since then was the custom vmOptions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your width and height should not be `match_parent` for a FAB - this doesn't make sense.  Try `wrap_content`.

Please note that the size of a FAB is specified by the [Material Design specs](https://material.io/design/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html).

Comment: This particular FAB is contained in a Linear Layout nested withing another Linearl Layout housing several rows of views, probably a design flaw but it was just working yesterday...;: )

Comment: Sorry but it still doesn't make sense :)  The FAB size should be `wrap_content` no matter what its container is.

Comment: I uploaded a picture. You guys are definitely right now that I think of it, bad design for sure, but when I set it to wrap_content the FAB icon size does in fact become proportional the FAB, but now the entire FAB is tiny.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "tiny" but per Material Designs specs a FAB can either be 56x56 or 40x40 (https://material.io/design/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html)

Comment: <sigh>  I have been trying to force enlarge the FAB. Guess I need to create a custom shape drawable with an onClick...